# Hlint suggestion: use uncurry

Tags: haskell, hlint

I have this line of code:

```
map (\(u,v) -> flatTorus n u v) gridUV
```

`Hlint` suggests me to replace it with

```
map (uncurry (flatTorus n)) gridUV
```

What is the motivation of this suggestion ? Is it for shortness only, or something else (performance) ? Because though it is longer, I find the first code more easy to read.

In fact my question is more general,, because this is just an example among others: does `Hlint` suggestions are generally based on a shortness motivation only or are there other improvements behind the suggestions ?

Comment: More readability I guess: if you know what `uncurry` does, there is less that people have to think about what is going on. I also think that `hlint` suggests `map (uncurry (flatTorus n)) gridUV` (with an extra pair of brackets).

Comment: Yes sorry, I forgot the brackets. I edit.

Comment: I think `hlint` suggestions are guided by both shortness and readability. Some of them probably would find a strong agreement in the community. Others, like this one, not so much. Personally, I find the second code not much better than the first one; I'd say they are nearly equivalent. Maybe `hlint` should also provide a weight to its suggestions.

Comment: Yes. One suggestion I really don't like is use `head x` instead of `x!!0`. I have not been able to disable this suggestion in VScode.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent: well using `x!!0` and `head x` are both not very elegant. You better use pattern matching for that, since it is not guaranteed that a list has an element. In fact `head`, `tail`, `(!!)`, and `length` are functions that should be avoided.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes but for example sometimes I do `Vertex3 (x!!0) (x!!1) (x!!2)`. It would be silly to use `head x` here.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I would write `let [a,b,c] = x in Vertex3 a b c`

Comment: @Li-yaoXia: well I think you have to keep a (possibly empty tail). But you can it like:

`f (x0:x1:x2:_) = Vertex x0 x1 x2; f _ = <something else>`

Comment: Why not write `[ flatTorus n u v | (u, v) <- gridUV ]`?

Comment: `hlint` does provide weights to its suggestions - this one is merely a suggestion rather than a warning. I regularly trim old suggestions based on feedback to try and follow the preferences of the community.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent you can disable extensions with a `.hlint.yaml` in the root directory. See https://github.com/ndmitchell/hlint/blob/master/.hlint.yaml#L59

Comment: @NeilMitchell Thanks! I will check that. Previously I used Atom and I was able to configure. But my Atom does not work anymore :-(

Comment: @NeilMitchell `- ignore: {name: Use head, within: HLint}` does not work. I put `.hlint.yaml` in the root directory of my stack project. Is it the right place to put it?

Comment: @NeilMitchell Ah ok, it works like this: `- ignore: {name: Use head}`. Fantastic!

Answer (score 2):

I think Hlint prefers using `uncurry` because it gives you an invariant representation of the callback. Lambda expressions are inherently sensitive to representation, since

```
\(u, v) -> flatTorus n u v
```

is equivalent to

```
\(x, y) -> flatTorus n x y
```

even though they are textually different.

Using `uncurry` frees readers of the cognitive load of doing alpha equivalence in their head (e.g., recognizing that the above two expressions are the same), but then saddles them with the cognitive load of having to remember a vocabulary of combinators. Ultimately, it's a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

These are not actually quite equivalent.

```
(\(x, y) -> (,) x y) undefined = undefined
uncurry (,) undefined = (undefined, undefined)
```

Do you should take any suggestion to use `uncurry` with a grain of salt. Think about whether that extra laziness will help, hurt, or make no difference.

Comment: The output from HLint actually includes "Note: increases laziness" in the above example.